# How to call - reset user password

Tags: c#, winforms

I have define the employee userID at the login page in order to save the development time. At the login page there is a button called 'Reset Password'. The process is that when I click on the reset button, the password inside the database will become NULL for that userID. I have manage to call the userID, but do not know how to set the password to become NULL.

Below is my code for the process flow.

```
Employee emp = null;
string src = "07070";

if (TransState.GetType() == typeof(EnterUserId) || TransState.GetType() == typeof(EnterPassword))
{
      if (Auth.GetEmpoyeeClassByBarcode(src, out emp) == 1)
      {

           // set the ui button fo successful user login
           int x = LoginCheckBarcode(src, out emp);
           //                    loadTask(auth);
           // Direct to login menu 
           Param.Operation = Constant.LOGIN;
           ChangeState(typeof(TaskSelected));
           return 1;

       }
       else
       {
           return 0;
       }
 }
```

Comment: I suggest you stick to an existing reset process rather than trying your own. There is no reason to set a password to null. What happens if there is an issue in your code, you just made someones password null and now your code crashes? The membership and security system is not done in a way "to save time" it needs attention and it needs to be done properly from the beginning

Comment: more over a null password could mean anyone can login because there is no password

Comment: Im trying to develop a system and currently at the testing process. My client want to have a Reset Button implemented at the login page. So the Reset button at the login page is required.

Comment: I think the Reset button should be clearing the content of the text boxes rather than setting the password in db to null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some extra validation other than just deleting the password otherwise anyone could just reset and delete the password and proceed to log in.

That being said, to change the password you would need to query your database which I assume is sql server since you list Winforms.

```
UPDATE table
SET password  = value
WHERE userID = value
;
```